# Xamarin TCP Socket Connection PC with Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm building A remote app in Xamarin Android and i have a problem in connection .
error : System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No route to host.

```
Client :-
Button con = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnConnect);
        var ip = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtIP);
        var port = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPort);
        var show = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtShow);
        var view = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
        show.Text = ip_address("");
    con.Click += delegate
        {
            IPEndPoint point = new 
IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip.Text),int.Parse(port.Text));
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(point);
            show.Text = "Connected";
        };

Server:-
TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5656);
            listen.Start();
            Socket sc = listen.AcceptSocket();
            MessageBox.Show("Connected");
Button con = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnConnect);
        var ip = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtIP);
        var port = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPort);
        var show = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtShow);
        var view = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
        show.Text = ip_address("");
    con.Click += delegate
        {
            IPEndPoint point = new 
IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip.Text),int.Parse(port.Text));
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(point);
            show.Text = "Connected";
        };
```

Comment: "No route to host" is a networking problem.  Are you sure your client has internet permissions enabled, and that it is trying to connect to an IP that is reachable from the device/emulator?  A very common problem is to attempt to use "localhost" or the loopback address to connect to a local server instead of the IP or FQDN.

Comment: now i have that error :System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll

Comment: Is this a Xamarin Forms or Xamarin Native Application? You have this tagged Xamarin Forms. Either way, if you can post a link to a sample that replicates the issue it would be easier to diagnose where you're running into trouble.